# Why MongoDB Java 3.0 driver which uses bulk upsert write and C++ 2.6 driver which does individual upserts have the same performance?

Tags: java, c++, performance, mongodb

The code below represents bulk write using Java 3.0 driver - 14 000 upsert operations at once and c++ 2.6 which do 14 000 individual upserts. The execution time of the Java and C++ code is the same - about 53 seconds. Why bulk write doesn't have performance benefit?

```
 // Java driver with bulk write operation (14 000 upsert operation  preapeared and executed in one bulk operation:


public void addBookInfo(String bookTitle, HashMap<String, Integer> bookInfo)
{
// insert information to the book collection
Document d = new Document();
d.append("book_title", bookTitle);
book.insertOne(d);
// insert information to the word collection
// prepare collection of word info and book_word info documents
List<Document> wordInfoToInsert = new ArrayList<Document>();
List<Document> book_wordInfoToInsert = new ArrayList<Document>();
for (String key : bookInfo.keySet())
{
    Document d1 = new Document();
    Document d2 = new Document();
    d1.append("word", key);
    d1.append("count", bookInfo.get(key));
    wordInfoToInsert.add(d1);
    d2.append("book_title", bookTitle);
    d2.append("word", key);
    d2.append("count", bookInfo.get(key));
    book_wordInfoToInsert.add(d2);
}
// this is collection of insert/update DB operations
List<WriteModel<Document>> updates = new ArrayList<WriteModel<Document>>();
// iterator for collection of words
ListIterator<Document> listIterator = wordInfoToInsert.listIterator();
// generate list of insert/update operations
while (listIterator.hasNext()) 
{
    d = listIterator.next();
    String wordToUpdate = d.getString("word");
    int countToAdd = d.getInteger("count").intValue();
    updates.add(
        new UpdateOneModel<Document>(
            new Document("word", wordToUpdate),

            new Document("$inc",new Document("count", countToAdd)),
            new UpdateOptions().upsert(true)
        )
    );
}
// perform bulk operation
// this is slowly
BulkWriteResult bulkWriteResult = word.bulkWrite(updates);


// C++ 2.6 driver - 14 000 single inserts executed one by one.

void DAO::addBookInfo(std::string bookTitle, std::map<std::string, int>   bookInfo)
{
// insert information to the book collection
BSONObjBuilder b;
b.append("book_title", bookTitle);
BSONObj d = b.obj();
connection.insert(book_collection, d);
// insert information to the word collection
// prepare collection of word info and book_word info documents
vector<BSONObj> wordInfoToInsert;
wordInfoToInsert.clear();
vector<BSONObj> book_wordInfoToInsert;
book_wordInfoToInsert.clear();
std::map<std::string, int>::iterator itr;
itr = bookInfo.begin();
while (itr != bookInfo.end())
{
    std::pair<string, int> wordInfo = *itr;
    BSONObjBuilder b1;
    b1.append("word", wordInfo.first);
    b1.append("count", wordInfo.second);
    BSONObj d1 = b1.obj();
    wordInfoToInsert.push_back(d1);
    BSONObjBuilder b2;
    b2.append("book_title", bookTitle);
    b2.append("word", wordInfo.first);
    b2.append("count", wordInfo.second);
    BSONObj d2 = b2.obj();
    book_wordInfoToInsert.push_back(d2);
    itr++;
}

cout << "wordInfoToInsert " << wordInfoToInsert.size() << endl;
cout << "book_wordInfoToInsert " << book_wordInfoToInsert.size() << endl;
// prepare Query document;
vector<BSONObj>::iterator witr;
// upsert info to word collection
witr = wordInfoToInsert.begin();
while (witr != wordInfoToInsert.end())
{
    BSONObj widoc = *witr;
    BSONObjBuilder bqwi;
    bqwi.append("word", widoc.getStringField("word"));
    BSONObj qwi = bqwi.obj();
    Query q(qwi);
    BSONObjBuilder buwidoc;
    buwidoc.append("$inc", BSON("count" << widoc.getIntField("count")));
    BSONObj uwidoc = buwidoc.obj();
    connection.update(word_collection, q, uwidoc, true);
    witr++;
}
```

Comment: Possible reason of this is the following. Bulk operation vs non bulk may have 2 differences.   1) In case of bulk it is possible to transfer over network entire job or at least to reduce network operations.  2) Having all sub jobs simultaneously it is possible to analyze them and try to optimize their execution.  I may be wrong, but it looks like MongoDB take advantage of 1 but not of 2.

Comment: I compiled the driver on OpenSuse 13.2 64 bit - same performance as on Windows 7 64 bit.